# How to define an empty Object Type in a GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql

I want to specify my GraphQL API in a schema, but I also want to spread my schema out among multiple files. I want to be able to use `extend type Query` or `extend type Mutation` to add queries or mutations to the overall schema. For example, my `user.graphql` file is as follows:

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
}

type UserResult {
    success: Boolean!
    errors: [String]
    user: User
}

extend type Query {
    user(userId: ID!): UserResult!
}
```

The `Query` Object Type is defined in a different file, `schema.graphql`:

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
    dummyField: Boolean
}
```

These files are combined when my application launches to produce the full API schema.

For `type Query` I have included a `dummyField` because I can't define an empty Object Type (one without fields) without getting an error. The following lines:

```
type Query {}
```

and

```
type Query {
}
```

Throw errors like:

> line 988, in expect_token f"Expected {get_token_kind_desc(kind)},
> found {get_token_desc(token)}.",
> graphql.error.syntax_error.GraphQLSyntaxError: Syntax Error: Expected
> Name, found '}'.

I would prefer for these Object Types to be empty to avoid the `dummyField` polluting my code and to make it clear that the intention is for `Query` and `Mutation` to be extended in other files.

I am using Flask with ariadne (0.13.0), which relies on graphql-core (3.1.5). I could not find anything in the most recent [GraphQL specification](https://spec.graphql.org/) about empty Object Types. Is it possible to declare empty Object Types in the schema, without using a placeholder field? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some digging I found this [GitHub Issue Comment](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/568#issuecomment-468789206) with the following syntax:

```
type Query

extend type Query {
  a: Boolean;
}
```

I applied this to the examples above and they worked.
Therefore, to create an empty Object Type, omit the curly braces `{ ... }`.

The GraphQL specification [here](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#ObjectTypeDefinition) indicates that the `ObjectTypeDefinition`'s `FieldsDefinition` is optional, although this is not abundantly clear.

[image: GraphQL June 2018 Edition Section 3.6 ObjectTypeDefinition]

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, there seems to be a bit of confusion in the spec around this, as there are other Type Validation sections that require types to define at least one field (https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sel-FAHZhCFDBAACDA4qe).

Also, other libraries such as `sangria` and `graphql-java` don't support empty types like shown in this example.